# providing date in x-axis in R

Tags: r

Can anyone please tell me how to give the start and end as dates in time-series in R. I know how to give a sequence, say:

```
ts <- ts(temp, start=1, end=10)
```

But I want to show starting at Jan 01 and ending in Jan 10 instead of just 1 to 10. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the following line will generate a sequence of dates: seq(as.Date("1910/1/1"), as.Date("1910/1/10"), "days")  Maybe that can help.  I am not sure.  Maybe include a reproducible example showing what you want.

Comment: Maybe this question will help also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843969/plotting-time-series-with-date-labels-on-x-axis

Comment: @Mark, I tried the seq, but it doesn't work inside ts command.

Comment: Without a small reproducible example it is difficult to offer much advice.  Perhaps you can use julian dates and then convert them to calendar dates for plotting. http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/CTFS/html/tojulian.html

Answer (score 1):

The basic time-series functionality in `ts` is probably not going to be enough for you. There are a lot of [available tools](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html) for working with time-series in R, but the `ts` class is geared towards representing

> "regularly spaced time series (using numeric time stamps). Hence, it is
>   particularly well-suited for annual, monthly, quarterly data, etc"

If you describe your data correctly, the `print` command will format it nicely. If you wanted your data divided into months, you could do something like this (note the `frequency` of 12):

```
> print(ts(round(rnorm(44)), start = c(2012,3), frequency = 12), calendar = TRUE)
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2012           2   1  -2  -1   1   1   0  -1   1  -1
2013   1   0   2   1  -1   1  -1  -1   0   2   1   2
2014   2   0  -1   0   1   1   0   0   2  -1   0   0
2015   2   0   0  -1   0   0   0   1   2   0
```

Since you want daily intervals, you're going to want to set `frequency` to 365:

```
> print(ts(letters, start = c(2013, 1), frequency = 365), calendar = TRUE)
     p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8 p9 p10 p11 p12 p13 p14 p15 p16 p17 p18 p19 p20 p21
2013  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t   u
     p22 p23 p24 p25 p26
2013   v   w   x   y   z
```

Which is going to look rather awkward, but will solve your problem in that it won't just give you a number for each day. However, as stated in the docs, the `ts` class only supports "numeric time stamps" so this is probably the best you're going to get with built in `ts` features.

If you want more advanced features I would have a look at some of the tools in [this documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html).

Comment: actually i know how to use c(2013, 1) which essentially means starting from Jan 1. But is there any other way to include the day there?? it doesn't even work like: start = 1910/1/1, end= 1910/1/10??

Comment: @ToNoY Not really, no. Why do you want it to work like that? The purpose of using `ts` is less about displaying the data, and more about  enforcing regularity of intervals for some more abstract calculations. If you just want dates, just use dates.