# R convert factor to date with month as characters

Tags: r, date

I'm trying to convert a factor to date but I keep getting NA values. The format of the date value I have as date is like: dd-mmm-yy. For example with the following code:

```
dates <- c('21-Feb-16', '22-Feb-16', '23-Feb-16')
valx <- c(100,200,300)
df.dates <- data.frame(dates, valx)
```

I have tried some of the examples in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843969/plotting-time-series-with-date-labels-on-x-axis), but when I try to convert the date I get an NA value

```
as.Date(df.dates$dates, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
[1] NA NA NA
```

My intention is to do a time line chart, but I cannot figure out how to convert the date properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong format string.  Instead, try:

```
as.Date(df.dates$dates, format = "%d-%b-%y")
[1] "2016-02-21" "2016-02-22" "2016-02-23"
```

Your original format used / but your data has -
Your original format had %Y  (which is for 4 digit years)
Your original format had %mmm but for 3 letter month abbreviations you need %b
The formats are documented with `strptime`