# Changing Horizontal Label axis in curve fitting in R

Tags: r

I have tried to plot sales order against time. graph is as follows:

[image]

I want to replace number of days by dates:
which means replace 0 by 22/09/2016

```
                50 by 11/11/2016
                100 by 31/12/2016
                150 by 19/02/2017
                200 by 10/04/2017
```

I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: There are many resources if you search for "how to plot dates r", e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843969/plotting-time-series-with-date-labels-on-x-axis).

Answer (score 1):

You will want to make use of the `xts` package which can handle daily values

```
library(xts)
v <- 0:200 # your data here
d <- seq.Date(as.Date('2016-09-22'), as.Date('2017-04-10'), length.out = 201)
plot(xts(v, order.by = as.POSIXct(d)))
```

Here is a great cheat sheet:
https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/r-xts-cheat-sheet#gs.1XjXRyI