# R model returned by ARIMA shows different Time on x-axis

Tags: r, time-series

I am a beginner in R TimeSeries analysis. I have a .txt file having comma separated values like below:

[image: data]

I have run the below commands:

```
dd <- read.zoo("data.txt", index.column = 1, sep = ",", format = "%Y-%m-%d", 
               header = TRUE, FUN = as.Date)
```

[image: str]

```
dd_xts <- as.xts(dd)
model <- arima(dd_xts, order=c(2, 0, 1))
```

Now, plotting the fitted values via:

```
plot(fitted.Arima(model))
```

[image: fitted]

which **does not** have the same values of Time as the initial xts object on X-axis, as shown below:

[image: original]

What is going wrong??

Comment: Try to use `as.Date`.

Comment: Have a look at this, it is quite similar to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843969/plotting-time-series-with-date-labels-on-x-axis

Comment: have already used as.Date in read.zoo() , so my data on plotting gives the second plot but issue is with the plot of values fitted by the arima model in the first plot .The first plot's x-axis doesn't show Time values as in the second one .

Comment: Missed to mention....dd_xts looks like below:.,
, [1]                                                                                      2017-01-01,338.9700000.                                        2017-01-02,4551.350000