# plot function type=“n” is ignored for plot(y~x)?

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot a graph of certain values against time using the plot function.

I am simply trying to change the representation of the dots, using the pch= function. However R is simply ignoring me! I have also tried removing the dots so that I can place labels instead, but when I type in type="n" it ignores that too!

I am using the exact same format of code that I have used for other plots but this time it just isn't cooperating. 
If I specify other features such as the title or the x/y axis labels, it will add those in but it simply ignores the pch or type commands.

This is my basic code:

```
plot(Differences ~ Time, data=subsetH)
```

But if I run

```
plot(Differences ~ Time, type="n", data=subsetH)
```

or

```
plot(Differences ~ Time, pch=2, data=subsetH)
```

it keeps plotting the same thing.

Is there something obvious I have missed?

Comment: I’m guessing the plot.method works differently for plot(x,y) compared to plot(y~x). What happens if you do plot(subsetH[,”Time”], subsetH[,”Differences”], type=“n”) ?

Comment: If I change the ~ to just a comma it doesn't work at all, it says it can't find object"y".

Comment: Did you paste exactly what i wrote? There is no data argument in the plot(x,y) — you have to subset each piece

Comment: Sorry, I obviously misread that, I didn't see the "What happens.." bit.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. I thought it might be to do with the ordering of ellipsis and `data` in the `plot.formula` function. Can you please post some example data, or try and reproduce the problem with `xs <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10))`. With the latter, `plot(y ~ x, pch = 4, data = xs)` works fine for me. Have you overwritten `plot`?

Comment: Evan, I've just tried it now, copying and pasting exactly but it says unexpected input in plot.... 
I see you may have some stray commas in there so I tried it without those but it says the same error message.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite a novice user so I don't know if I'll be able to do that, Russ. I'll have a go.
What do you mean, have I overwritten plot?

Comment: Russ, when I try the xs data frame you've suggested, and the plot command you have suggested, it works. It just doesn't work for my data.
I can't make sense of it. I've tried shutting down R studio and starting it again in case it's some kind of glitch but it didn't help.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce the problem. All these behave as expected: `plot(disp~mpg, data=mtcars)`, `plot(disp~mpg, data=mtcars, type='n')`, and `plot(disp~mpg, type='b', data=mtcars, pch=2)`. Can you provide a sample of `subsetH`? Perhaps the output from `dput(x)` where `x` is a representative sample, perhaps from `head(subsetH,n=10)`.

Comment: @Zlata80, you said to Evan that there were stray commas ... I don't see any, what is "stray" from your perspective? You may get an error if you don't correct the pretty-quotes (`“n”`) for simple-quotes (`"n"`), but not "unexpected input", are you sure you pasted it correctly?

Comment: r2evans, I thought maybe the commas just inside the square brackets were not supposed to be there, although I tried with them and without them.

Comment: I've just tried it again now, and if I change the " " to the basic ones as you suggest, it does work in that it generates a plot but I am still getting marks on the graph rather than it being blank. It plots short little horizontal lines rather than points, but I'm trying to make it blank .... OR if i try to use the pch= command, I'm still getting these little horizontal lines. I'm wondering now if it is to do with it being time on the x axis which is continuous, perhaps?

Answer (score -1):

I just came across your question because I encountered the same thing - creating an empty plot did not work, as type='n' was always ignored (as well as other type specifications).

With the help of this entry: [Plotting time-series with Date labels on x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843969/plotting-time-series-with-date-labels-on-x-axis) 
I realized that my date format needed to be assigned as "date" class (as.Date()).
I know your entry dates back a little bit already, but maybe it's still useful.