# Order of dates when plotting time series in R

Tags: r

I would like to know if the **order of dates matter** when plotting a **time series** in R.

For example, the dataframe below has it's date starting from the year 2010 onwards increasing as it goes down, for example till 2011:

```
Date         Number of visits

2010-05-17    13
2010-05-18    11
2010-05-19     4
2010-05-20     2
2010-05-21    23
2010-05-22    26
2011-05-13    14
```

and below where the year are jumbled up.

```
Date         Number of visits

2011-06-19   10
2009-04-25   5
2012-03-09   20
2011-01-04   45
```

Would i be able to plot a time series in R for the second example above? Is it required that in order to plot a time series, the dates must be sorted?

Comment: Please check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843969/plotting-time-series-with-date-labels-on-x-axis) - main idea is to *Since the times are dates be sure to use "Date" class, not "POSIXct" or "POSIXlt"*

Comment: @PoGibas why not make it into an answer?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Isn't this a duplicate? I just wanted to make sure that OP understands the problem

Comment: While the answer is similar or the same, I think the question about order of dates in a data.frame is different and valid.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data shown reproducibly int he Note at the end create an ordering vector `o` and then plot the ordered data:

```
o <- order(dat$Date)
plot(dat[o, ], type = "o")
```

or convert the data to a zoo series, which will automatically order it, and then plot.

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(dat)
plot(z, type = "o")
```

### Note

The data in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "Date         Number of visits
2010-05-17    13
2010-05-18    11
2010-05-19     4
2010-05-20     2
2010-05-21    23
2010-05-22    26
2011-05-13    14"
dat <- read.csv(text = gsub("  +", ",", readLines(textConnection(Lines))),
 check.names = FALSE)
dat$Date <- as.Date(dat$Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

`as.Date` slove your problem:

```
data$Date <- as.Date(x$Date)
ggplot(data, aes(Date, Number_of_visits)) + geom_line()
```

[image]